# Creating Table View in ViewDidAppear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am creating a Table View in viewDidAppear, because my app requires it to be created here for multiple reasons.  However I notice that I get a memory leak when I analyze my application.

I thought using the instance variable _tableView is not a good idea in any other method besides init and dealloc.  Should I just use autorelease, I want to make sure the table gets released at the appropriate time.

There is a property for my Table View.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
```

And I create the Table View as such:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]
                      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300) 
                      style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    // Table View properties
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.tableView = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_tableView release];
}
```

Comment: In dealloc you should use [self.tableView release] and self.tableView = nil; and you are safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autorelease.  You get one retain for the alloc and another for the property assignment (assuming it's a retained property).

Your dealloc should handle one and an autorelease the other.

Comment: So autorelease and then set [_tableView release] in dealloc?

Comment: Yes.  The Product->Analyze menu option is a good tool for catching this kind of thing.  It points out probable leaked objects, both where they're created and where their references go out of scope.  (Though, actually, your viewDidDisappear: may make the dealloc's release into [nil release], which would be pointless but not damaging.)

Answer (score 2):

`self.tableView` is a `retain` property, so your synthesized setter increases the retain count.  But when you create a new `UITableView` using `alloc`/`init`, you also increase the retain count.  So this line results in `tableView` being retained twice:

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]
                  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300) 
                  style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Once when you use `alloc`/`init`, and once when you call the synthesized setter using `self.tableView =`.

You do not have two corresponding `release` calls.

The proper way of handling this would be to `autorelease` the `alloc`/`init`'d UITableView object that you set `self.tableView` to, like so:

```
self.tableView = [[[UITableView alloc]
                   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300) 
                   style:UITableViewStyleGrouped]
                  autorelease];
```

The rest of your code will work as expected.

As an aside, you probably don't want to create your `UITableView` in `viewDidAppear`.  By that time your view has already appeared (hence the name), and you likely wanted your `UITableView` before that.  You also probably don't want the CPU expense of creating a new `UITableView` every time the view appears.  You probably want to create a `UITableView` in `viewDidLoad` and then reuse it, unless there is a really good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Setting property is good, i set the property for instance variable when you want to use that variable in another class, otherwise it is not necessary ,

Since you are creating in viewDidAppear it will create always when the view appears for that controller so better relesase the tableview in ViewDidDisappear method.

If you use autorelease we wont get when it will be released so some times accessing tableview will cause crash of application,

Answer (score 0):

On top of what the other guys have said, I'd discourage you from doing `alloc` in `viewDidAppear` because that method can be called multiple times depending upon what else goes on (and, by the way, cause leaks unless you start checking for the existence of a tableView before `alloc`'ing another). Doing it in `viewDidLoad` seems to be much safer.

As an aside, I believe that your `viewDidAppear`, `viewDidDisappear` and `dealloc` should all be calling their `super` versions, too.

Comment: I didn't copy in the [super ...], but they are all calling that.  The view hierarchy is completed so viewDidLoad is not always being called so that is why I am attempting this is viewDidAppear.

Comment: If I release in viewDidDisapear, is the if (self.tableView == nil) necessary before I alloc?  wouldn't it always be nil before viewDidAppear is called?

Comment: (1) if you balance your allocs in viewDidAppear with releases in viewDidDisappear, that's probably fine;

Comment: (2) it's more customary to do your allocs in viewDidLoad (or, for non UI objects, in init);

Comment: (3) I personally don't like the idea of getting rid of a UIView's subviews just because you're pushing another controller or something (which is the effect of doing it in viewDidAppear/Disappear). You have a view which exists, which you've removed some stuff from with the idea of adding it back when that view appears again. Seems like cumbersome logic.

Comment: (4) the entire notion behind ARC is antithetical to this alloc'ing and releasing as views appear and disappear.

Comment: colinbrash articulates a far more logical reason for not doing it in viewDidAppear. On top of my concerns, it's just plain too late!